# Download file from site PHP

Tags: php, download

I would to know the command in a PHP script to get in output and save a file from my site.
Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that you would like to know how to initiate a file  download for the user browsing your site?

Comment: Sorry, it's not very clear what you want. Could you try to explain it in different words or by example?

Comment: *(reference)* http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php (see Example #1 Download dialog)

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://www.ryboe.com/tutorials/php-headers-force-download) for a good description of how to force the output of a php script to be a download.

The basics of it are:

```
// Set headers
 header("Cache-Control: public");
 header("Content-Description: File Download");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" + $filename);
 header("Content-Type: application/zip"); // or whatever the mime-type is
                                          // for the file you want to download
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

 // Read the file from disk
 readfile($full_path_to_file);
```

As an addition (provided by Gordon's comment), see the 1st example on the php documentation [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score 0):

At the End of the files or used in clicking files, you can add this

```
        $filesh = "check.xls";

        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($filesh));
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        readfile($filesh);
```

if you got any header using problem means, top of the file you can add ob_start(); function

Answer (score 0):

If you mean getting output, contents from other site or location, this what you need [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)