# how to download data from current PHP webpage

Tags: php, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make PDF file downloadable in HTML link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364946/how-to-make-pdf-file-downloadable-in-html-link)
>   [Download file from site PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651747/download-file-from-site-php)

I have a PHP web page that contains a fairly large table of data that is dynamically obtained from a database. Part of the job spec states that there needs to be a download link on the page. This download link will save the tabular data to a file, and will present the user with a save dialog box so that he can name the file. After the file is downloaded I want to page to still be visible in the browser window.

I've done this before, but I can't recall the details. I'm thinking about something like this pseudo-code, putting it in a separate file:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=huge_document.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
<while not finished>
display row of data
<end>
```

and then link to it like this:

```
  href="downloadfile.php?page=mypage">download file</a>
```

Apologies if this is already discussed on the site. I did not find a specific case that fit my requirements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787493/serving-a-file-download-using-php?rq=1

Comment: Jurgen, I think you are right. Your link looks like it answers my question. Sorry for wasting everyone's time on this.